# how to convert json tree to table, and back(same table to json tree)

Tags: json, postgresql, tree

i need to convert json tree to table, and back(same table to json tree), **PostgreSQL**
example:

```
{
"id": 1,
"title": "Example Node(UnDeleteable, and no counted)",
"items": [
{
"id": 2,
"title": "dfsdfs",
"items": [
{
"id": 3,
"title": "dfsfddfsfd",
"items": [
{
"id": 4,
"title": "dsffdsdfsfdsdfs",
"items": [
{
"id": 5,
"title": "dfsdsfdfsddfs",
"items": []
}
]
}
]
}
]
}
]
}
]
```

need to be:

> ```
>             ParentId  ChildId   title
>
>             NULL        1    "Example Node(UnDeleteable, and no counted)"
>             1           2    "dfsdfs"
>             2           3    "dfsfddfsfd"
> ```
>
> etc
>   ....
>   ...
>   ...
>   someone can help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: No sure what PostgreSQL has to do with your tree Json but have you tried this http://www.jstree.com/ ?

Comment: You'd be a lot better off writing this in V8, which, you can do in postgres. I wouldn't even attempt it with SQL, it's a bad idea.

Comment: Although, you could likely convert the table to JSON.. I could do that for you fairly easily using a CTE to do a hierchial query then doing a row_to_json on the results

Comment: What is your preferred programming language ?

Comment: Why does your table stop at three rows, when your json has five elements?

Comment: c,c++,php, and my table didnt stop, i wrote "etc..."(you will figure", and i need to convert it into postgresql table, and from postgresql to json tree

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is a two-dimensional array and recursion.
here is my code about tanslating a json to a tree. I think it is easy to feed your needs with a little modification.

```
var jsonTreeServ = {};
jsonTreeServ.toTreeJson = function (jsonObj, treeArr) {
    for (var k in jsonObj) {
        var val = jsonObj[k];
        if (val instanceof Object) {
            var node = {};
            node.title = k;
            node.value = '';
            node.visible = true;
            node.nodes = [];
            treeArr.push(node);
            jsonTreeServ.toTreeJson(val, node.nodes);
        } else {
            var node = {};
            node.title = k;
            if(null!==val && ''!==val){
                node.title += '=';
                val = jsonTreeServ.translateTimestamp(node.title, val);
            }
            node.value = val;
            node.visible = true;

            treeArr.push(node);
        }
    }


    return treeArr;
}
```